# What type of router (non wifi) for DHCP assignment?

Tags: networking, home-networking, dhcp

So I have a pretty large house that use to be connected to a business network that had a DHCP server.  However we've disconnected that business network and put in residential internet so I need a new way to assign DHCP to all wireless clients.

The new internet connection in the house has a modem (Motorola Surfboard SB6120) that when anything is attached to the ETH port it assigns it the public IP address (like my laptop for example).  I have three 3Com wireless access points (business class I think) that all broadcast the same SSID so they can hop from one to the other without the clients even realizing it (depending on which part of the house they are in). They do NOT assign DHCP (even though they could if needed).

I need to put something in between the cable modem and these 3com access points to assign DHCP addresses.  Whenever I look for a router they all seem to be wireless, which I really don't need (becuase I have the 3coms).  Is there something I can buy that I could put in between my cable modem and 3com WAPS to assign DHCP and still use my 3com access points?  I don't think having all three 3Com's assigning DHCP would work would it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just turn off the wireless in the router you buy if it's an issue?

Comment: many cable modems have dhcp server in them. which cable modem are you using?

Comment: Cry, I thought of that but wondered if I could find a non-wifi router.  
@daya, Motorla Surfboard SB6120.  I didn't think that would be possible because when I hook up my laptop to the Ethernet port on the Motorla, it gives out the public IP.  I'll look into this realy quick.  THANK YOU BOTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most residential wired routers should do what you need. [This is just an example of what is available at Best Buy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Routers/Wired-Routers/abcat0503009.c?id=abcat0503009) (note some of these are commercial-grade or VPN appliances). I can't seem to get Amazon to filter non-wireless routers but they have some as well.

You can also buy a wireless router as this is likely what you'll find in most stores and turn off the wireless features.

**Edit**: [Amazon link for non-wireless routers](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_8?rh=n:172282,n:!493964,n:541966,n:172504,n:300189&bbn=172504&ie=UTF8&qid=1326392563&rnid=172504#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=node=300189&field-keywords=-wireless&rh=n:172282,n:!493964,n:541966,n:172504,n:300189,k:-wireless) (and other things apparently).

Comment: Yea I think the wireless router (with wireless turned off) is my best option here.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I need to put something in between the cable modem and these 3com access points to assign DHCP addresses

You **must** to check before buy, that your 3Com allow DCHP-relay (they *can allow* and *can disallow*), in order to distribute DHCP-reply to clients.

More easy (and natural) way (for me) will be (as suggested before) to allow DCHP-server on all 3Com, use separate nets on each AP, maybe add static routes for inter-AP communication